# C(++): Replace function declaration with macros but not its invocations

Tags: c++, macros

I have a library I can't change where some function is declared, implemented and used, in single file. Lots of other stuff is done in that same file. I want to override that single function to do another thing. The issue is that when I use renaming macro, all the places where that macro/function name is found are replaced, both declarations and invocations. I want some way to rename only declaration or invocations. Then I'll be able to simply drop-in my own function under initial name as a replacement.

The code looks like this:

```
// library-module.cpp

int foo(int a, int b)  // declaration
{
    return a+b;
}

int bar()
{
    return foo(1, 2);  // invocation
}


// main.cpp

// MAGIC HAPPENS HERE
#include "library-module.cpp"

int foo(int a, int b) // drop-in replacement
{
    return a-b;
}

int main()
{
    return bar(); // should be -1, not 3
}
```

Another option would be to do a vice-versa operation: to replace all invocations to some other symbol, but not the declaration. Though it's not preferred, because there might be other users of that function name in the wild.

Yet another option would be to do it in runtime, but I believe it's not that great.

Thank you.

**UPD1**:

It's c++.

Here are the actual function [declaration](https://github.com/apollovy/Cataclysm-BN/blob/upload/src/newcharacter.cpp#L120), [implementation](https://github.com/apollovy/Cataclysm-BN/blob/upload/src/newcharacter.cpp#L1950) and [usage](https://github.com/apollovy/Cataclysm-BN/blob/upload/src/newcharacter.cpp#L447) in the file.

What I wanted is to substitute a single line of the function `set_scenario`, not touching anything else, from my other app that uses all that app's code. The idea was to keep the maintenance of all the code, except that very function, to the core team, and to handle this one myself, because i need some specific implementation. Thus I am including not the headers, but the implementation, and want such a dirty hack. Maybe I'm on the wrong way?

In the end I've made a fork, changed the line and settled with this, though I believe it would've been better if I didn't do a fork, because it becomes way harder to get the changes.

Another thought that comes to my mind is possibly I've to make a patch for the function I'm to change and apply it on every build. This way it would be precisely known what was that single line that changed, and I would immediately know that the initial function changed if I had patch applying error. Maybe this is a better way of achieving the same thing?

And in the end, it was very interesting for me do deal with that using macros, because it's rather black magic to me.

Thank you again.

Comment: C or C++? Can you show the *exact* function declaration and usage? Details might be important.

Comment: You can disable a macro with `#undef MACRO_NAME`, would that work?

Comment: You don't usually include `.cpp` files, just `.h` files.

Comment: Define the macro *after* you define the function it replaces.

Comment: If OP is using C++, would defining the function they wish to override in a custom namespace be a good solution?

Comment: **Patching the object file** so the original function calls yours, seems a better solution. If the library does not do in lining and such. _Back to the roots!_

Comment: I've updated the description, does that clarify everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may or may not be possible depending on how exactly the function is defined and used.

Assuming the exact declaration and usage you've shown, you can do this:

```
#define foo(a, b) FOO_LOW(CAT(DETECT_, a) CAT(DETECT_, b))(a, b)

#define CAT(a, b) CAT_(a, b)
#define CAT_(a, b) a##b

#define DETECT_int ,

#define FOO_LOW(...) FOO_LOW_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOO_LOW_(a, ...) CAT(FOO_IMPL, __VA_OPT__(_DECL))

#define FOO_IMPL(a, b) replacement(a, b)
#define FOO_IMPL_DECL(a, b) foo(a, b)


constexpr int foo(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
constexpr int replacement(int a, int b) {return a - b;}

static_assert(foo(100, 10) == 90);
```

This implementation requires C++20, and additionally MSVC needs `/Zc:preprocessor` and Clang (13 and earlier, see [bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51609)) needs `-Wno-gnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments`. It's possible to implement with an earlier standard and without those flags, but the macro will be more convoluted.

This specific implementation has some limitations:

- It checks if both arguments start with `int`, so if it happens in a function call, it will be incorrectly considered a declaration, e.g. `foo(int(1), int(2))`.
- If an argument contains a `,` outside of `(` `)`, you get a compilation error, e.g. `foo(std::array{1,2}[0], 1)`.
- If an argument begins with a punctuation, you get a compilation error, e.g. `foo((1), (2))`.

Comment: Impressive preprocessor-foo, +1.  And a sufficiently complex and situation-specific result (even *with* using very new, C++-specific / non-standard features) that I am satisfied that for most people, for most intents and purposes, my "you can't" is true in practice.  And "you shouldn't" is true pretty much everywhere else.

Comment: This is awesome, you just gave me a whole new level of macro magic understanding. It's now not that black for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that when I use renaming macro, all the places where that macro/function name is found are replaced, both declarations and invocations.

Yes.

> I want some way to rename only declaration or invocations.

The preprocessor doesn't know the C or C++ language.  It knows how to recognize identifiers, but it does not understand their C or C++ context, so as to distinguish declarations from other uses.  Therefore, if you have a block of code that you cannot modify, then you cannot use the preprocessor to selectively replace only some appearances of a given identifier within that block, and not others.

Even if you could modify the code in question, many kinds of identifiers can be declared multiple times in the same scope, as long as they are not *defined* more than once.  Thus, although in principle you could go through the code and insert `#define` and `#undef` directives at all the places needed for a given identifier to be recognized as a macro name in all declarative contexts, that is not easier in the general case than just modifying the declarations directly.

Overall, this just sounds like a bad idea from the beginning.  It's not clear what to recommend as an alternative, however, because the question provides no detail about the higher-level goal or why the proposed approach sounded attractive.

Comment: It could be possible, depending on how exactly the function is used. E.g. you could check if both arguments begin with `int`, and then consider it a declaration. But it would break if someone does `foo(int(1), int(2))`...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I invite you to explain how to implement that with the preprocessor.

Comment: Posted an answer.